# How to find the smallest distance between two 4-sided objects in 3D space?

Tags: 3d, algorithm, convex-hull

I was wondering if there is a way to calculate the smallest distance between two 4-sided objects in space. In this specific scenario, the only information I know about both of them are the 4 points that make up their vertices (so 8 points in total). Is there a way to achieve this?

Also, I'm considering that both shapes have a non-zero volume and that they do not intersect each other.

Comment: Separating Axis Theorem is our usual go-to for computing separations between simple polyhedra. Have you tried applying that to your case?

Comment: I didn't exactly know how to extend it to 3D. Do you have any good material on the theorem so I can read about it again? (my memory of it is a tad hazy).

Comment: I'll confess I just search for it whenever I need to refresh my memory of the details. [I also happened across a thread recommending GJK for tetrahedra](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54125933/3064164) - GJK being [the Gilbert-Johnson-Keerthi distance algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Keerthi_distance_algorithm).

Comment: GJK was a great find, but I couldn't really understand how to find the actual distance value between the shapes. I will look more into it, thanks for telling me about it!